# How to move an UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to do an app like Facebook with the menu that appears on the left when you push on the panel button. To do that, I have a first UIViewController with an UITableView, and another put above with a modal transition without animation. To display the UITableView (my menu), I want to move my second UIViewController on the right.

How can I do that ? It is the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you need is provided as a template.**
Check this git..download it..and play around with it..

https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController

Answer (score 1):

How can I do that ?

Just used a UIView animation to move the view of the view controller. Add another view that is your menu, and move that using the same animation. It's actually pretty easy.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    [menu setFrame:CGRectOffset([menu frame], [menu frame].size.width, 0)];
    [mainView setFrame:CGRectOffset([mainView frame], [menu frame].size.width, 0)];
}];
```

It is the right way ?

I don't know what you mean by "the right way"... Sooooo, maybe?

Comment: Thanks, for the "right way" my english is not still perfect, I'm sorry ^^