# Draggable ViewController like the iPhone facebook app

Tags: ios, draggable, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm wondering how to go about implementing a draggable viewcontroller such as that in the Facebook app where the user can drag from the far left of the screen to the right and the viewcontroller will follow, revealing another view underneath. I'm not looking to rip off this design, I just find it to be a very interesting way to display extra information and I'd like to learn more about draggable interfaces.

Now I'm somewhat familiar with UIPanGestureRecognizers but I imagine this is far more complex?

Where would I start?

Comment: I would find my solution preferable, because you can swipe anywhere on the top view controller to open/close.  This is the most similar to the new FB app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this with pretty good luck:

[ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

I did my research on all the options at the time (like a month ago) and this is most like facebooks because you can drag anywhere on the screen to move it.  Also this supports both orientations

Answer (score 1):

You can find solution here: [How to move an UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968877/how-to-move-an-uiviewcontroller)

In that example you can drag viewControllers by swiping navigationBar

In that example FronViewController viewDidLoad method contains code:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealGesture:)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer];
```

and ZUUIRevealController contains method to handle recognizer:

```
- (void)revealGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```